# How should I go about managing images online for a game mod?

Tags: java, database, image, web

I am working on a mod for a game. Currently, the mod checks to see if an image (the image is a texture for the 3d model) with the filename that is the username is online at a certain location (So currently, I'm using Dropbox to hold these images, so it checks with my public directory).  If that image is online, it renders a model on the player and applies that image to the model.

I can manually upload images (with the username as the filename) up to the website that holds the images, but I plan on making this mod public and obviously that won't work if hundreds of players want to use this mod.  What I need is when the user ticks or unticks the option to apply that model to their character, the image will become available or unavailable to the client, allowing the client to decide whether to render the object or not on the player.

I don't know anything about databases or web design/coding and I only have a vague idea on how to go about this.

I need some way to make the image available or not. Should I:

- Have the filename change?  So something like from `eegabooga.png` to `eegaboogaunused.png`
- Have a MySQL database that has the images and a boolean.  So `true` means it's a used image and `false` means it's unused? (Sorry if that makes no sense, I have no knowledge about MySQL or any sort of databases).
- (Something you think would be better).

Sorry if this makes little sense.  I will try to explain anything in further detail if you need, just ask.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Does the image have to be prepared/preprocessed by you or why do you need to load it from an online site -- why not keep it local to the client? Where is the "(un)ticking to apply that model" supposed to happen -- in the game, on a web site, ...? Why would the remote image need to change at all, the client (un)ticking a checkbox would be enough to toggle the display of the extra model?

Comment: @philipp Because the game has multiplayer features and by storing the image online, it will allow the users to see other users images and 3d objects.

Answer (score 0):

So - I'm guessing the checkbox exists outside the mod? Otherwise, the mod should handle the hide/show of the file.

If the checkbox is on a website, then use that website to control access. Route all image requests through the website, and let the website redirect the request on to DropBox or Amazon S3 if access is permitted - otherwise, reject the request with a 404.

Comment: I'm still unsure on how I'm going to handle the *checkbox* part of it. Either I can have the client send a signal to the web server to make the change to the file or have it handled on the website. How I will handle that will be decided after I find out how to handle the images.  My problem is that all the images will be online, I just need a way to handle if the images are *available* or not.  Should I change the permission of the image when the signal to toggle it?  Can this be handled with MySQL? The dirty details on how to go about doing this are what I need help with.

Comment: Well, I think you could modify the permissions best if you use Amazon S3 directly(I believe it's what dropbox uses). It has a decent API, and you will avoid the normal permissions loss that probably would occur if you ever had to move your data. You will need some kind of authorization system, though, unless you want any user to be able to modify any users's image permissions. THAT is actually a difficult problem, unless you the game servers have an authorization API you can use.